# Can not set ChromeOptions capability

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, chrome-options, desiredcapabilities

What `maven` dependency should I add in my `pom.xml` and what library should I import in order to set this `ChromeOptions` capability?

```
opts.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
```

Need to set it in order to avoid the following exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : abuse limit triggered}

Answer (score 0):

Well, the imports here are:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.UnexpectedAlertBehaviour;
```

I really don't understand why my IDE didn't auto-suggest me them?